# Started Hue Server, CLI says 8000, config says 8888, in reality: Nothing

Tags: django, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs, hue

I have started a Hue Server running on an EC2 instance with a pseudo distributed setup of HDFS. When I start the server, the CLI states that the server is running on `localhost:8000`:

```
0 errors found                                                                                                                                                
<CURRENT DATE>                                                                                                                                    
Django version 1.6.10, using settings 'desktop.settings'                                                                                                      
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/                                                                                                         
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However, the config tells it to launch on `localhost:8888`:

```
### hue.ini sample

# Webserver listens on this address and port
http_host=0.0.0.0
http_port=8888
```

Cool, whatever. But when I try to access the Hue UI using the EC2's public IP (`<public IP>:8000` and `<public IP>:8888`), nothings shows up on neither `port 8000` nor  `port 8888`. I've tried to change `hue.ini` to point to `port 8000`, which does nothing.

I have created the necessary security groups to allow my machine to access the port.

Here is some of the debugging I have done:

```
>> sudo netstat -atnp | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      22644/python2.7

>> sudo netstat -atnp | grep 8888
**NOTHING**

>> lsof -i:8000 
**NOTHING**

>> lsof -i:8888
**NOTHING**

>> ps -ef | grep hue
root    22644    1  0 23:08 pts/0    00:00:18 /usr/local/lib/hue/build/env/bin/python2.7 ./build/env/bin/hue run server
```

So, nothing is listening on `port 8000` and `port 8888`, but Hue's process is running (at least I think). Why is this happening? How can I work around this to access the Hue UI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to start the dev server, the command should look like

> ./build/env/bin/hue runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

if you want it to be accessible from another host (and probably need a nohup ... &).

Note that

> ./build/env/bin/hue runcpserver

is the correct command for starting the production server.

You can also check with hue.ini is picked-up later by looking at the /dump_config page when you can access it.

Comment: Hey man, thanks I saw your post on the Hue-Users group. `./build/env/bin/hue runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` was what I ended up doing to get the server up and running.

Comment: @romain Please explain what is the `/dump_config page` and how to access it.